# Swift Charts (iOS 16) Pie / Donut Chart

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-charts

Is it possible to create a pie / donut chart using Apple's new SwiftUI Charts framework?

There are images of a pie chart shown in the WWDC videos. Any help or code sample on how to create the pie chart will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not supported yet, you can use `Circle()` & `trim` to build one though.

Comment: Thanks @Timmy, I am moving from my custom library to the apple one and in the WWDC they are shown pie chart in the examples, but couldn't find any documentation

Comment: I got reply from Apple Developer Technical Support that, Currently there is no support for pie charts in Swift Charts.  I recommend filing an enhancement request asking for this functionality

Answer (score 12):

Swift Charts does not (yet?) support polar geometry, which is what you need to build pie charts.

I would recommend using a `Canvas` and drawing the information yourself, something like this:

```
struct Pie: View {

    @State var slices: [(Double, Color)]

    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            let total = slices.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.0 }
            context.translateBy(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)
            var pieContext = context
            pieContext.rotate(by: .degrees(-90))
            let radius = min(size.width, size.height) * 0.48
            var startAngle = Angle.zero
            for (value, color) in slices {
                let angle = Angle(degrees: 360 * (value / total))
                let endAngle = startAngle + angle
                let path = Path { p in
                    p.move(to: .zero)
                    p.addArc(center: .zero, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: false)
                    p.closeSubpath()
                }
                pieContext.fill(path, with: .color(color))

                startAngle = endAngle
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

struct Pie_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Pie(slices: [
            (2, .red),
            (3, .orange),
            (4, .yellow),
            (1, .green),
            (5, .blue),
            (4, .indigo),
            (2, .purple)
        ])
    }
}
```

[image]

To make a donut chart, clip the canvas as the first thing you do in the rendering closure:

```swift
let donut = Path { p in
    p.addEllipse(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    p.addEllipse(in: CGRect(x: size.width * 0.25, y: size.height * 0.25, width: size.width * 0.5, height: size.height * 0.5))
}
context.clip(to: donut, style: .init(eoFill: true))
```

[image]

Comment: I got reply from Apple Developer Technical Support that, Currently there is no support for pie charts in Swift Charts.  I recommend filing an enhancement request asking for this functionality

Comment: Any suggestions for how to cut in half and still keep the complete chart output?

Comment: Ash! Just change 360 to 180 

Comment: Can you please provide some context on how is the donut clipping working?

Comment: @rjgonzo clipping means you set an area on the canvas that drawing will happen in; think of it like a stencil being held over the canvas

Answer (score 3):

**iOS 17 and later**

As of iOS 17, pie and donut charts are now included in Apple's Charts framework.

---

***Simple pie chart example:***

[image]

Add a SectorMark to create a pie chart.

```
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(PieData.data, id: \.id) { element in
            SectorMark(
                angle: .value("Count", element.count)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", element.type))
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
    }
}
```

---

***Simple doughnut chart:***

[image]

Add an innerRadius to the SectorMark to create a donut.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(PieData.data, id: \.id) { element in
            SectorMark(
                angle: .value("Count", element.count),
                innerRadius: .ratio(0.5)
            )
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", element.type))
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
    }
}
```

---

Pie chart with added features:

[image]

Add angularInset to create spacing between sectors.

Add annotation to label the sectors.

Add chartLegend to hide the chart's legend.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.id) { element in
            SectorMark(
                angle: .value("Count", element.count),
                angularInset: 2.0
            )
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", element.type))
            .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
                VStack {
                    Text(element.type)
                        .font(.caption)
                    Text("\(element.count, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))")
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
        }
        .chartLegend(.hidden)
        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
    }
}
```

---

***Doughnut chart with added features:***

[image]

Add angularInset to provide spacing between sectors.

Add cornerRadius to add rounded corners to the sectors.

Add annotation to label sectors.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.id) { element in
            SectorMark(
                angle: .value("Count", element.count),
                innerRadius: .ratio(0.5),
                angularInset: 2.0
            )
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", element.type))
            .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
                    Text("\(element.count, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
    }
}
```

---

Example data used above:

```
let data = [
    ShapeModel(type: "Circle",    count: 12),
    ShapeModel(type: "Square",    count: 10),
    ShapeModel(type: "Triangle",  count: 21),
    ShapeModel(type: "Rectangle", count: 15),
    ShapeModel(type: "Hexagon",   count: 8)
]

struct ShapeModel: Identifiable {
    var type: String
    var count: Double
    var id = UUID()
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to move the annotations outside of the pie chart?

Comment: Possibly but in my testing only the overlay and centered annotation seems to work with pie charts at this time.

Comment: How to change the colors of the pie chart?

Answer (score -8):

Yes it is possible in Apple's new swift UI by using **charts**, **swiftUI and foundation** libraries

Comment: Even though OP asks whether it's possible, he wants to know _how_. This answer is not helpful as it is.

Comment: thanks @DarkDust for the clarification, in the WWDC video they are showing many more types of charts including pie but there is no code or sample or documentation :(

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).